# different dataset in switch in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 datasets in a single report, out of the 5 columns 2 are derived from dataset1 and 3 from dataset2 (dataset 2 being the primary dataset). Now when I try to use the below switch command,it does not give me any error but doesn't show any results. The dataset1 is a share point list.

```
=SWITCH(First(Fields!xyz.Value, "dataset1")="Platinum",25,First(Fields!xyz.Value, "dataset1")="",0,First(Fields!xyz.Value, "dataset1")="Gold",15)
```

All the other columns in the tablix are from dataset2 and the report runs fine just no data comes in this column

Comment: I was able to do this for a column which was returning a number   =SWITCH(First(Fields!abc.Value, "dataset1")=1,"Platinum",First(Fields!abc.Value, "dataset1")=3,"Gold"). This works perfect, I am not able to understand why it is not working when it is a string, I tried it with another column with string value and it did not show any results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `First()` expression is probably the problem, and the reason it's working when you change the IIF condition. First() just literally fetches the first value in the named field from the target dataset, so if it's not "Platinum", an empty string or "Gold" it will just return nothing. On the otherhand, if the first value of abc is 1 or 3 it will always return "Platinum" or "Gold"

It's important to realise this will return exactly the same data on every single row of the table, since you're only ever looking at the FIRST row of dataset1.

I think you're probably after the LookUp() function, which will use primary keys to match the datasets and fetch different data from dataset1 depending on the data in the current row of dataset2.

Hope that sort of makes sense?

EDIT IN REPLY TO COMMENT:

You can do this in two ways then. You can either use the same LookUp() formula that you use to populate the column in your switch statement to get the points, for example;

```
=Switch(LookUp(Fields!application_name.Value, Fields!application_name.Value, Fields!service_level.Value, "dataset1") = "Platinum", 25, LookUp(Fields!application_name.Value, Fields!application_name.Value, Fields!service_level.Value, "dataset1") = "Gold", 15)
```

Secondly, you can refer directly to the column that is already fetching "Gold" or "Platinum". For example if that textbox is called Textbox10 (check the top right of the properties panel to see the name) then you can use:

```
=Switch(ReportItems!Textbox10.Value = "Platinum", 25, ReportItems!Textbox10.Value = "Gold", 15)
```

Either method should work fine. Basically what you're doing there is ensuring you always check the right service level for that application rather than just the first one in dataset1

Comment: Thanks Dan, Ya it does makes sense now, I understood now what the First() expression does. What I am trying to do is, I have 2 datasets, one contains the application names and their service level( sharepoint dataset) the other contains service desk ticket info , along with what the application name is(sql server dataset), i used lookup to populate the column with the service level where the application name matched. Now I want to use that column value to assign point values to this colum, like when its platinum= 25, gold =15.this is where m stuck.any ideas? I tried removing first(),doesnt work

Comment: I ran out of characters in this comment, so I've edited my original reply to answer this comment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, appreciate it. When I used lookup inside the switch it worked, somehow using the reportitems.texbox29.value was not fetching any results. (curios?) but the other statement did the trick.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!